# Bluetooth adapter for my 3.5mm headset

Tags: headset

I need to buy a new phone and all the phones I may like don't have a 3.5mm jack for my headset, that I want to keep using. For that end I would need a bluetooth adater that I can connect my headset to and the adapter would connect to my phone via Bluetooth.

That adapter would have to receive audio from my phone and send mic and command signals simultaneously. Does anybody know about such a device? The best i could find was a device with its own command buttons and its own builtin mic. But I want to use the buttons on my headset and the mic on my headset. There is a bunch of Bluetooth adapters available but they can only send or receive audio. I need a device that lets me use my old headset as if it was a Bluetooth headset. Is there such a device?

Comment: @Izzy No hard feelings. I saw that one comming. HardwareRecs doesn't appear in the Technology section of SE. They sure seem the better site for this. I also think my question is reasonable in terms of their [quality guidelines](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/206). I see you are a moderator. Can you transfer my question to that site?

Comment: @Izzy FWIW I found [this question] (https://android.stackexchange.com/q/131735/192883) so I thought maybe my question is not too far out, but yeah ... I already put my concerns in the disclaimer. There is not much more I could do :D If you could transfer my question to HardwareRecs, that would be really cool.

Comment: The linked question doesn't ask for hardware, that's the difference. And HardwareRecs is still in Beta, which is why it's not yet listed in the technology section (only "mature" sites are). As you have checked and verified it fits there, I'll migrate it over now. Good luck there!